# Excel: Compounding matrix generation with array inputs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Task:** To output an array of scalar products based on input array of boolean values and scalars.

**Requirements:** The solution needs to be formulaic (i.e. contained in one cell) and done without the use of VBA -> the solution needs to be dynamic to accommodate different input arrays.

*Input array A* (Boolean values)

| >= | 2023 | 2024 | 2025 | 2026 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2024 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2025 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2026 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

*Input array B* (Scalar values)

| 2023 | 2024 | 2025 | 2026 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.25 | 1 | 1.2 | 1.05 |
| 1.35 | 1.1 | 1 | 1.2 |
| 1.25 | 1.15 | 1.05 | 1.05 |
| 1.3 | 1 | 1.1 | 1.15 |
| 1.25 | 1.1 | 1.4 | 1.35 |

*Output array* (Compounded scalars)

| 2023 | 2024 | 2025 | 2026 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.25 | 1.25 | 1.5 | 1.575 |
| 1.35 | 1.485 | 1.485 | 1.782 |
| 1.25 | 1.4375 | 1.509375 | 1.58484375 |
| 1.3 | 1.3 | 1.43 | 1.6445 |
| 1.25 | 1.375 | 1.925 | 2.59875 |

**In practice:** the columns of *Output array* are comprised of row-wise products of the *Input array B*. For example the first column is only the 2023 scalars, but the third is 2023 * 2024 * 2025 on each row (i.e. 1.25 * 1 * 1.2, for the first value of the third column). As such, the *Output array* has the same amout of columns as *Input array B*, with each column's values being a product of the current and the preceding columns of *Input array B*.

**Note:** The format of *Input array A* is irrelevant in the sense that the boolean values just need to indicate which elements of a particular row are multiplied together -> the array can be changed if needed, but *Input array B* should remain as provided.

**Bruteforce solution:** This task can be completed with MAKEARRAY() but it becomes exceedingly inefficient when *Input array B* has thousands of rows.

**Solution found:**

[image]

Comment: I don't see the utility of input array A. Assuming that input array B is placed in range A1:D6, you can obtain the output array you have posted in range F2:I6 using `=IF(E2="",A2,E2*A2)`.

Comment: Then again if input array A does matter and the output you reported is incorrect, assuming your input array B is in range A1:D5, your input array A is in range F1:I5, you can obtain the output array you have posted in range K2:N5 using `=IF(J2="",IFERROR(INDEX($A2:A2,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$2:A2)/$F2:F2,1)),""),IF(F2,J2*A2,J2))`

Comment: Input array A is not strictly necessary, as the boolean values can be obtained implicitly from the columns since each year has one in the input and output (i.e.  year 1, ..., year n) -> I just care about a solution to getting from Input array B to the output using a singe-cell formulaic solution. Both of your suggestion resulted in a single value, rather than an array output.

Comment: I did some reverse engineering and came up with a dynamic single-cell solution using vector operations (TOCOL(), WRAPROWS(), BYROW() etc.). Works with different years and scalars, I'll test the efficiency on Monday, but this one should be orders of magnitude faster than MAKEARRAY().

Answer (score 0):

Copy this in a new sheet:

| USER INPUT |  |  | CALCULATION RANGE |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Range | Sheet1!A2:BH6 |  | Index | =IFERROR(D2+1,1) | =IFERROR(E2+1,1) | =IFERROR(F2+1,1) | =IFERROR(G2+1,1) |
|  |  |  | Starting formulas | =(OFFSET(INDIRECT($B$2,TRUE),0,INDIRECT("R[-1]",FALSE)-1,,1)*(COLUMN(INDIRECT($B$2,TRUE))>=INDIRECT("R[-1]",FALSE))+(COLUMN(INDIRECT($B$2,TRUE))<INDIRECT("R[-1]",FALSE))) | =(OFFSET(INDIRECT($B$2,TRUE),0,INDIRECT("R[-1]",FALSE)-1,,1)*(COLUMN(INDIRECT($B$2,TRUE))>=INDIRECT("R[-1]",FALSE))+(COLUMN(INDIRECT($B$2,TRUE))<INDIRECT("R[-1]",FALSE))) | =(OFFSET(INDIRECT($B$2,TRUE),0,INDIRECT("R[-1]",FALSE)-1,,1)*(COLUMN(INDIRECT($B$2,TRUE))>=INDIRECT("R[-1]",FALSE))+(COLUMN(INDIRECT($B$2,TRUE))<INDIRECT("R[-1]",FALSE))) | =(OFFSET(INDIRECT($B$2,TRUE),0,INDIRECT("R[-1]",FALSE)-1,,1)*(COLUMN(INDIRECT($B$2,TRUE))>=INDIRECT("R[-1]",FALSE))+(COLUMN(INDIRECT($B$2,TRUE))<INDIRECT("R[-1]",FALSE))) |
| CONSTANTS |  |  | Extraction | =IF(E2<=$B$5,RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(E3),LEN(FORMULATEXT(E3))-1),"") | =IF(F2<=$B$5,RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(F3),LEN(FORMULATEXT(F3))-1),"") | =IF(G2<=$B$5,RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(G3),LEN(FORMULATEXT(G3))-1),"") | =IF(H2<=$B$5,RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(H3),LEN(FORMULATEXT(H3))-1),"") |
| Columns count | =COLUMNS(INDIRECT(B2,TRUE)) |  | Index substitution | =SUBSTITUTE(E4,RIGHT(FORMULATEXT($B$6),LEN(FORMULATEXT($B$6))-1),E2) | =SUBSTITUTE(F4,RIGHT(FORMULATEXT($B$6),LEN(FORMULATEXT($B$6))-1),F2) | =SUBSTITUTE(G4,RIGHT(FORMULATEXT($B$6),LEN(FORMULATEXT($B$6))-1),G2) | =SUBSTITUTE(H4,RIGHT(FORMULATEXT($B$6),LEN(FORMULATEXT($B$6))-1),H2) |
| Index substitute | =INDIRECT("R[-1]",FALSE) |  | Range substitution | =SUBSTITUTE(E5,RIGHT(FORMULATEXT($B$7),LEN(FORMULATEXT($B$7))-1),$B$2) | =SUBSTITUTE(F5,RIGHT(FORMULATEXT($B$7),LEN(FORMULATEXT($B$7))-1),$B$2) | =SUBSTITUTE(G5,RIGHT(FORMULATEXT($B$7),LEN(FORMULATEXT($B$7))-1),$B$2) | =SUBSTITUTE(H5,RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(E5),LEN(FORMULATEXT(E5))-1),E2) |
| Range substitution | =INDIRECT($B$2,TRUE) |  | Chaining | =IF(F6="",E6,F7&"*"&E6) | =IF(G6="",F6,G7&"*"&F6) | =IF(H6="",G6,H7&"*"&G6) | =IF(I6="",H6,I7&"*"&H6) |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| WARNINGS |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Calculation range width | =IF(MAX(2:2)<B5,"ENLARGE TO COLUMN "&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",OFFSET(E:E,0,B5-1)),"$",""),1,""),"Acceptable") |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Formula lenght | =IF(LEN(E11)>8192,"TOO LONG","Acceptable") |  | Formula | ="="&E7 |  |  |  |

This is not a solution. This is a meta-solution: a solution to get to the solution. Specify the range of input array B (minus the headers) in cell B2. Enlarge (to the right) the calculation range (E2:H7) accordingly to your need. Range B10 will inform you if the calculation range is to be enlarged. The actual formula you need will be reported in cell E11. Copy it, paste it where needed, press F2, confirm it as array formula (Ctrl+shift+enter).

Answer (score 0):

`=LET(a,A2:D6,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(a),COLUMNS(a),LAMBDA(r,c, SUM(1*PRODUCT(INDEX(a,r,SEQUENCE(,c)))))))`

Where `A2:D6` is `Input array B`

[image]